# Key Error thrown when trying to use <input>

Tags: python, html, django

I've tried to pare down the code so its not overly cluttered. 
I want to receive the number of repititions from an html form and create as many entries as the user as identified. Here I want to say make, 12 consecutive payments if the user says 12 on the "months" input field

```
template.html:
<form action="" method="post">
    Name: {{ form.name }}
    Date: {{ form.date }}
    <input type="text" alt="months" name="months">
    <input type="submit" alt="register" class="" value="Submit"/>
</form>

views.py
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        months = range(int(form.cleaned_data['months']))
        for m in months:
            line = LineItem(
            name    = form.cleaned_data['name'],
            date    = date.today() + relativedelta(months=m),
            )
        line.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/lines')
    else:
        pass
else:
    pass
```

I got a KeyError with this and if I take out the int(), I just get 1 entry but not the 12 or whatever number was prescribed.

```
class CreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        fields= ('name','date')
        widgets = {
        'date': DateInput()
        }
```

**Edit**: added form, fixed syntax, traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/lines/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'bet',
 'love')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Patrick/Dropbox/CrushFolder/tenant/love/views.py" in LinesAll
  33.           months = range(form.cleaned_data['months'])

Exception Type: KeyError at /lines/
Exception Value: 'months'
```

Comment: do you have some kind of data sample for `form.cleaned_data`? Maybe do some debug logging on that method, but from your code I can't tell what is happening

Comment: Traceback of the KeyError and classdef of CreateForm please. And I assume your views.py indentation isn't actually like that (it'd be a SyntaxError). And your form tag is missing a method; not sure if that's part of what's "pared down", but replace it if so, it's an important part to rule out as the source of the problem.

Comment: I dont really know what you mean by data sample, Im sending numbers through. It returns 3 as u'3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"months"` isn't a field that's being validated or examined by the form. This will fix your immediate issue:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # change:
    #months = range(int(form.cleaned_data['months']))
    # to:
    months = range(int(request.POST['months']))
```

But bigger picture: You shouldn't be using `ModelForm`. A), it's needless complexity, B), this isn't actually a form where the user sets attributes that are used to create a `LineItem` instance. Instead, this is a form where you're getting data that is then used to drive *application logic* that actually constructs the `LineItem` instances, with generated values (namely, the successive month-offsetted dates). Lose the ModelForm, do a regular form with "name" and "months" fields, and then `form.cleaned_data` will have the items you'd expect (`"name"` and `"months"`), which you can then use in the `LineItem()`-creation loop.

Comment: Your right it worked! but if I'm now using request.POST instead of form.cleaned_data, doesn't that mean I can no longer use form.cleaned_data or should I create a separate view that handles cleaning the data in the views.py file?

Comment: Right - you *should* use form.cleaned_data, but months isn't one of the form fields defined for `CreateForm`. Imo, define a regular `forms.Form` subclass with `months = forms.IntegerField()` and `name = forms.CharField(max_length=whatever)`, and `.cleaned_data` will have what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are returning a response with the first item in your loop.

Let me isolate this for loop.. note at the bottom it is exiting the loop immediately.

```
                line = LineItem(
                name    = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                date    = date.today() + relativedelta(months=m),
                )
                line.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/lines')
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped with the for loop when I made months = an integer but I still get thrown a key error if I try to use the form data

Comment: Is this how you mean I should call cleaned_data?[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)